# Can you Scale Site by +200% based on min-Width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This may not be possible without manually changing all the font / image css code but before I did that, I wanted to check if there was a way to do this...

Basically when you visit my site now on a large monitor (imac 27") it looks like this:

[image: current version]

However, the site looks a lot better if I cmd+ it to 200% which looks like this (similar to that of a default macbook pro laptop resolution:

[image]

I know I can do a lot of custom changes to make it work but wanted to know if there was a quick / easy way to make a site scale by x% based on resolution?  I plan on revamping the front end soon so don't want to spend a lot of time on this short term solution - curious about it though academically as well though.

Maybe it's as simple as making container-fluid & then making the background show be 70% of document height through jquery?

Comment: Are you using the class "container" to wrap the content?

Comment: jsfiddle or post a sample of code. it will help us see the behavior

Comment: In this example yes, but another I'm using container-fluid.  However, simply having container-fluid doesn't resolve the sizing issues.

Its the image sizes, scale, etc.. just pressing the comand+ to scale up my size to 175% or 200% looks great.  I can do it the hard way using EMs and %s and stuff but was just trying to see if there was a simple way to auto zoom into a screen "if resolution =xxx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that with CSS media queries and zoom property. 
Check out the following code

```css
/* large desktop */
@media all and (max-width: 1920px) {
    body {
        background-color: pink;
  zoom: 200%;
    }
}

/* small desktop */
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
  zoom: 100%;
    }
}

/* tablet */
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        background-color: orange;
  zoom: 100%;
    }
}

/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
  zoom: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for but had no luck googling it.

Comment: CSS zoom property is non-standard and is not recommended. Neither does it play well with media selectors that is used for layout, like bootstrap.